# Fixing Fading Text Using fadeToggle() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I'm trying to use `fadeToggle()` to make text from an array fade in, wait 10 seconds, than fade out for another text to do the same thing.

This code makes the text switch every few seconds perfectly, i just can't get the right code to make it fade in/out:

```js
var texts = [" \" It's really hard to design products by focus groups. A lot of times, people don't know what they want until you show it to them. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs ", " \"  Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" That’s been one of my mantras — focus and simplicity. Simple can be harder than complex ; you have to work hard to get your thinking clean to make it simple. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" The present is theirs ; the future, for which I really worked, is mine. \" <br /> ~ Nikola Tesla ", " \” The value of an idea lies in the using of it. \“ <br /> ~ Thomas Edison "];
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeText() {
    $(".quote").html(texts[count]);
    count < texts.length ? count++ : count = 0;
  }

  setInterval(changeText, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="quote">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this logic:

1. Fade out.
2. Change text.
3. Fade in.

```js
var texts = [" \" It's really hard to design products by focus groups. A lot of times, people don't know what they want until you show it to them. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs ", " \"  Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" That’s been one of my mantras — focus and simplicity. Simple can be harder than complex ; you have to work hard to get your thinking clean to make it simple. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" The present is theirs ; the future, for which I really worked, is mine. \" <br /> ~ Nikola Tesla ", " \” The value of an idea lies in the using of it. \“ <br /> ~ Thomas Edison "];
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeText() {
    $(".quote").fadeOut(250, function () {
      $(this).html(texts[count]).fadeIn(250);
    });
    count < texts.length ? count++ : count = 0;
  }
  setInterval(changeText, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="quote">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

To cross-fade in text you need to put them in separate elements and fade them in/out as needed. You cannot achieve a fade just by changing the `text` property of an element.

With that in mind you can place the `h1` elements within a contained and position them absolutely so that they overlap. You can then use chained `setTimeout` calls to fade the needed content. Try this:

```js
var texts = [" \" It's really hard to design products by focus groups. A lot of times, people don't know what they want until you show it to them. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs ", " \"  Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" That’s been one of my mantras — focus and simplicity. Simple can be harder than complex ; you have to work hard to get your thinking clean to make it simple. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs", " \" The present is theirs ; the future, for which I really worked, is mine. \" <br /> ~ Nikola Tesla ", " \” The value of an idea lies in the using of it. \“ <br /> ~ Thomas Edison "];
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeText() {
    $('.quote').fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $('<h1 class="quote">' + texts[count % texts.length] + '</h1>').appendTo('.quote-container').fadeIn();
    count++;
    setTimeout(changeText, 3000);
  }

  changeText();
});
```

```css
.quote-container h1 { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-container">
  <h1 class="quote">Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Also note the use of the modulo operator (`%`) over the ternary to check the `count` value.

Comment: Why @parveen's solution is not better? I'm sorry about this question but as much as I know you (via your comments and your answer on SO) you are very expert and maybe I miss something but your solution is more complexly for no reason.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's better or worse, I was just in the process of writing the answer as Praveen posted his. The difference with mine is that it cross fades the element (ie. one fades out at the same time another fades in so there's never a white gap). Praveen's solution fades one out, then fade in the next. It's simply down to the OP which method he'd prefer to use.

Comment: +1 for using modulo - a really nice little trick. _"You cannot achieve a fade just by changing a property of an element."_ - no, you absolutely can... this is very straightforward with the `classList API` and CSS transitions. And arguably even simpler using a single CSS `@keyframes` animation (see my alternative answer).

Comment: @Rounin True, although I meant more specifically that you can't cross fade only the `text` property. I updated the answer to be more accurate in that regard

Answer (score 1):

A different approach.

I understand that the question asks about jQuery `fadeToggle()`, but I'd want to suggest that CSS `@keyframes` is probably the best tool for this kind of animated presentation.

**Working Example using CSS:**

```js
var texts = [
    " \" It's really hard to design products by focus groups. A lot of times, people don't know what they want until you show it to them. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs ",
    " \"  Design is not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs",
    " \" That’s been one of my mantras — focus and simplicity. Simple can be harder than complex; you have to work hard to get your thinking clean to make it simple. \" <br /> ~ Steve Jobs",
    " \" The present is theirs ; the future, for which I really worked, is mine. \" <br /> ~ Nikola Tesla ",
    " \" The value of an idea lies in the using of it. \" <br /> ~ Thomas Edison "
];


var count = 0;
var quote = document.getElementsByClassName('quote')[0];

function changeText() {
    quote.innerHTML = (texts[count]);
    count < (texts.length - 1) ? count++ : count = 0;
}

setInterval(changeText, 6000);
```

```css
.quote {
animation: fadeToggle 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeToggle {
0% {opacity: 0;}
33% {opacity: 1;}
66% {opacity: 1;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<h1 class="quote">Hello</h1>
```